# How to use advanced options in filter_() using ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, wrapper

I am using the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) wrapper.

I'd like to mimic this ffmpeg command via this wrapper.

```
ffmpeg -i multiaudio.avi -map 0:a:0 multiaudio_test_a01.wav
```

What this does, is to take the first audio track from the video and save it as separat audio file with the best quality possible.
More information to the advanced option "map": [ffmpeg map documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

Now using the wrapper I tried something like:

```
    (ffmpeg
 .input(filepath)
 .filter_('map', map='0:a:0')
 .output(str(os.path.splitext(filepath)[0]) + "_test_a01.wav")
 .run()
 )
```

Now the important line, that keeps throwing errors is this one:

```
.filter_('map', map='0:a:0')
```

Could someone please tell me, how I need to rewrite this line of code to make it work?

EDIT: Error Message

```
Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument [...] raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err) ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)
```

Thank you.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Unrelated to the syntax issue, but `-q:a 0` is ignored by the WAV muxer, so you can remove it. WAV is uncompressed, so that is why `-q:a` does nothing.

Comment: @furas the error is: 
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
[...]     raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)

Comment: @llogan fair point, removed this via edit. main question remains.

Answer (score 1):

As the ffmpeg paramameter "-map" is an advanced option and not a filter, the parameter needs to be specified for the output like so:

```
(ffmpeg
 .input(filepath)
 .output(str(os.path.splitext(filepath)[0]) + "_test_a01.wav", map="0:a:0")
 .run()
 )
```